# Easiest way to check if a user is coming from a given IP block and redirect?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ip

Here's the code I wrote in the Application controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  before_filter :redirect_if_bolivia

  private

  def redirect_if_bolivia
    if (bolivia_ip_block).includes? request.remote_ip
        #redirect user to www.foo.com
    end
  end

  def bolivia_ip_block
    %w {
        12.144.86.0 - 12.144.87.255
31.201.1.176 - 31.201.1.179
46.36.198.101 - 46.36.198.105
46.136.172.0 - 46.136.172.255
63.65.11.0 - 63.65.12.254
65.173.56.0 - 65.173.63.255
67.23.241.179 - 67.23.241.198
72.32.164.56 - 72.32.164.63
72.46.244.32 - 72.46.244.47
74.91.16.48 - 74.91.16.55
74.91.16.208 - 74.91.16.215
74.91.20.48 - 74.91.20.71
74.112.134.120 - 74.112.134.127
74.112.135.104 - 74.112.135.111
74.205.37.16 - 74.205.37.23
78.24.205.32 - 78.24.205.47
98.129.27.88 - 98.129.27.95
98.129.91.40 - 98.129.91.47
166.114.0.0 - 166.114.255.255
167.157.0.0 - 167.157.255.255
174.143.165.80 - 174.143.165.87
186.0.156.0 - 186.0.159.255
186.2.0.0 - 186.2.127.255
186.27.0.0 - 186.27.127.255
190.0.248.0 - 190.0.255.255
190.3.184.0 - 190.3.191.255
    }
  end
end
```

So basically, what is the easiest way to check if a `request.remote_ip` belongs to a Bolivia IP block?

I don't think that iterating through each block and spitting out a corresponding IP, adding it to an array is efficient. In fact, that would lead to me create an array of thousands of entries **for every single request.**

I'm sure this is not a new problem, so I'd love a proven solution to this.

Maybe I can check if the first three octets match, then it belongs to the block? How would I do that simple string comparison in Ruby?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can convert the subnets to [CIDR](http://ip2cidr.com/) notation since blocks are not arbitrary.  Then you can take advantage of [IPAddr#include](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/ipaddr/rdoc/IPAddr.html#method-i-include-3F)

```
require 'ipaddr'

class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  before_filter :redirect_if_bolivia

  private

  def redirect_if_bolivia
    if bolivian_blocks.any? { |block| block.include?(request.remote_ip) }
        #redirect user to www.foo.com
    end
  end

  def bolivian_blocks
    %w{
      12.144.86.0/23
      31.201.1.176/30
    }.map { |subnet| IPAddr.new subnet }
  end
end
```

Comment: I'm not that familiar with IP subnetting (*I failed that course back in Uni*), how would I know when to put in "/25" or "/30"?. Also, is "ipaddr" a default lib in Ruby or a gem I have to fetch?

Comment: IPAddr is in the standard library and should be included already.  You can find out the "/NN" by using the link (I edited in after) provided.  It takes the ranges you have and gives you the "/NN" you should use.

Comment: Ok, I've added in all blocks however, when I run `rails -s` and try it out, I'm not redirected at all. I've removed the conditional and redirected regardless, and it works so the redirect code is OK, the problem lies with the check between MY IP and the blocks I listed. Am I using a different IP if I test my application locally?

Comment: You're probably testing with 127.0.0.1.  You can add 127.0.0.0/8 to the list of blocks and it should redirect you.

Comment: Thank you that put me at ease; the filtering is now working correctly. Thanks for your help.